# Reference table by name for table_array parameter in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to specify a table by name for the `table_array` parameter in the lookup functions. For example, my formula now looks like this:

> =VLOOKUP([@Product],Table5[#All],1,FALSE)

How can I reference the table by its name `Products` instead of `Table5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename your table.

Select your table then under `table tools>Design tab>properties>table name box` you can rename it to whatever you want.

[microsoft help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/rename-an-excel-table-HA010223129.aspx)